# How to get self-referenced table tree structure, based on parent node in tree?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a way, to query whole tree structure (including top parent, to end bottom child), base on querying based on top parent.

BUT! It should return:
- strucuture (more than one element),
- or one element only (top level structure, if there is no childs below - but in this case, only if there is nothing "higher" - the **ParentID** IS NULL in this case).

I.e. having table with:

```
|--------------|
|ID  | ParentID|
|--------------|
|229 | NULL    |
|230 | 229     |
|231 | 229     |
|232 | 229     |
|233 | 229     |
|              |
|300 | NULL    |
|301 | 300     |
|302 | 301     |
|303 | 302     |
|304 | 300     |
|              |
|305 | NULL    |
----------------
```

Based on querying for *229*, the result should be:

```
229
230
231
232
233
```

Based on querying for *230*, or *231*, or *232*, or *233*, the result should be **empty**!

Based on querying for *300*, the result should be:

```
300
301
302
303
304
```

Based on querying for *301*, the result should be:

```
301
302
303
```

Based on querying for *302*, the result should be:

```
302
303
```

Based on querying for *303*, or *304*, the result should be **empty**!

Based on querying for *305*, the result should be:

```
305
```

Comment: Why `303` when you querying `301`?

Comment: Because *303* is child id *302*, where *302* is child od *301*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556720/how-to-get-self-referenced-table-tree-structure-based-on-any-node-in-tree/53556830#53556830) from your previous question to match the new requirements. You need to add a check in the recursive CTE when starting to traverse the hierarchy, to see is this a parent node or are there any children of it:

```
declare @Table table(ID int, ParentID int)

insert into @Table(ID, ParentID) values
(229, NULL),
(230, 229 ),
(231, 229 ),
(232, 229 ),
(233, 229 ),

(300, NULL),
(301, 300 ),
(302, 301 ),
(303, 302 ),
(304, 300 ),

(305, NULL )

declare @LookingForId int = 305
; with cte as (
  select ID from @Table t1 where t1.ID = @LookingForId and (t1.ParentID is null or exists (select * from @Table t2 where t2.ParentID = t1.ID))
  union all
  select t.ID from @Table t inner join cte on cte.ID = t.ParentID
)
select * from cte
```